# c++ std::thread calling method from object cause to calling destructor of this class

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, destructor

I have a few question about this code:

```
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    ~A()
    {
        std::cout << "Destructor A: " << this << std::endl;
    }

    void operator()()
    {
        std::cout << "going to sleep 10 seconds.." << std::endl;
        sleep(10);
        std::cout << "wake" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "begin" << std::endl;
    A* a = new A();
    std::thread th(*a);
    th.join();
    std::cout << "end" << std::endl;
    delete a;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
g++ -std=c++17 test.cpp -pthread
./a.out 
begin
Destructor A: 0x7fff0b6bed27
going to sleep 10 seconds..
wake
Destructor A: 0x559d4e8012a8
end
Destructor A: 0x559d4e801280
```

1. Why right after calling std::thread th(*a) I actually got a destructor call? it doesn't make sense.
2. Why there are 3 calls to the same destructor from different instances? In my code I created 1 instance of A and I delete it in the end of main function. so it should be just 1 print of A destrutor.
3. when calling std::thread th(*a), is the constructor of std::thread use 'a' as a reference or it creates a new instance of it (by calling copy constructor of A)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Since `std::thread` can't be sure that the value you passed to it will exists after creating the thread, it makes a copy of the value you passed.
2. Another copy done by `decay_copy`, called in `std::thread`'s constructor.
3. New instance.

You can have a detailled explanation of `std::thread`'s constructor here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread